Please help me find a religious-fantasy Indian movie involving a guy trying to marry a princess
There's a movie I watched once in my childhood and really liked. I can't remember the exact date of release, but it must be at least 10 years ago.
It is an Indian movie, colored.
The setting is pretty old I believe. I don't remember anyone using a gun.
It's a fantasy movie, with some comedy. Or a comedy movie with fantasy.
I'm pretty sure the movie is in English.
Some details of the plot I remember:
The main character joins a contest to marry a princess, there she met a woman.
The woman tries to turn the protagonist into a bad guy and forced him to a casino, and in a few days, he became very bad.
The women really liked the protagonist and asked him to marry her, but the protagonist refused. After the protagonist went bad after the casino, he became some sort of a stoner and accepted the wedding.
Then the woman was unhappy with their situation and drank some sort of potion together with the protagonist and forgot what happened in the few days they knew each other. 
The protagonist went back to the contest. In the end, there's some sort of bus that came and everyone just went to the bus and left the contest. 
During the end of the contest, the protagonist was asked a question about Ouroboros, and all the contestant starts meditating.
During the meditation, the protagonist realized something about life and was chosen to read people's wishes to a god or something. His soul was transferred but his body was still meditating. Seeing this, the woman carried his body on her back.
The god resembles a giant sleeping baby. Then the baby woke up because the protagonist failed to read a wish (from the woman he met?) and the world got destroyed.
Then the world went back to pre-civilization with some cavemen resembling some character from the earlier parts of the film.

That's pretty good plot details. But do you remember the language you watched this movie in? Please add if you remember this.

What kind of movie was it? Animation, Sci-fi, etc.
